# How to decode file name

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, zip, decoding

When I try to get the names of files from the uploaded archive, I get their names in this form `»α«ß»Ñ¬Γ ê. ƒ¬«ó½Ñóáπ½¿µá ïÑ¡¿¡ß¬«ú« è«¼ß«¼«½á, ó αá⌐«¡Ñ ñ. 1, Æû îÆé µÑ¡Γα, ¡á ßóÑΓ«Σ«αÑ`. The archive was created on windows 10. When I collect the archive on ubuntu and collect the file names from the archive, there is no such problem.
How can this be fixed?

The archive was sent by the client. It is not clear how to repeat such an error locally

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile('arhive.zip') as myzip:
    for name in myzip.namelist():
        try:
            uname = name.encode("IBM437").decode("utf-8")
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            uname = name.encode("IBM437").decode("IBM866")
        except UnicodeEncodeError as err:
            uname = name
    
        print(uname)
```

Comment: Do you know what exception path is being followed here?  What if you `print(name, uname)` what do you get?

Comment: What's the original `name` and what's the desired `uname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to see how the file is decoded in the zipfile library. And I saw the following condition:

```py
filename = fp.read(centdir[_CD_FILENAME_LENGTH])
flags = centdir[5]
if flags & 0x800:
    # UTF-8 file names extension
    filename = filename.decode('utf-8')
else:
    # Historical ZIP filename encoding
    filename = filename.decode('cp437')
    # Create ZipInfo instance to store file information
```

It only handles two cases:

1. All cases except Windows
2. If the archive was created in Windows. This is cp437 encoding

But sometimes files from MacOs end up in the 2nd condition filename.decode('cp437'), although they should in the first one and we need to decode from cp437 to utf-8.
Initially I did this

```py
if is_ok:
    try:
        # For files from macOS
        uname = name.encode("IBM437").decode("utf-8")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        # For files from Windows
        uname = name.encode("IBM437").decode("IBM866")
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        return False
...
if not is_ok:
    function(is_ok=False)
```

I found out that an already encoded file name can come into the function and then the function will return False. And the next names will not be decoded.

Answer (score 1):

You face this [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case:

```
name = '»α«ß»Ñ¬Γ ê. ƒ¬«ó½Ñóáπ½¿µá ïÑ¡¿¡ß¬«ú« è«¼ß«¼«½á, ó αá⌐«¡Ñ ñ. 1, Æû îÆé µÑ¡Γα, ¡á ßóÑΓ«Σ«αÑ'
print( name.encode( 'cp437').decode( 'cp1125'))
```

> ```
> проспект И. Яковлеваулица Ленинского Комсомола, в районе д. 1, ТЦ МТВ центр, на светофоре
> ```

or

```
print( name.encode( 'cp437').decode( 'cp866'))
```

> ```
> проспект И. Яковлеваулица Ленинского Комсомола, в районе д. 1, ТЦ МТВ центр, на светофоре
> ```